graphql api for guest to create account on checkout success page graphql
I am using the default api to create customer for a guest user to create account
mutation {
createCustomer(
input: {
firstname: "Bob"
lastname: "Loblaw"
email: "bobloblaw@example.com"
password: "b0bl0bl@w"
is_subscribed: true
}
) {
customer {
firstname
lastname
email
is_subscribed
}
}
}
But after creating the account on my orders page it does not show the order placed as a guest
I need the graphql api to create account for guest on the checkout success page which after creating the account shows the order also that was placed as a guest. pls help
